# Script of javascript blocks ui thread

Tags: javascript

My js-script calculates a lot of data.
For instance, sql.js updates my sqlite database.
I want to create a callback with probress bar and text. But the text in html web page is always not updated until the all of my calculations be done.

```
$array.each(function(index){
// CODE CODE CODE

        $("#pbData").text(index + ' PROGRESS');
        add_line_to_db(db,table_name,name,text);
// CODE CODE CODE
    });
```

I tried to use something like

```
$array.each(function(index){
// CODE CODE CODE
        setTimeout(function(){$("#pbData").text(index + ' PROGRESS');},1);
        add_line_to_db(db,table_name,name,text);
// CODE CODE CODE
    });
```

But it hasn't helped.

How to fix it?

**EDIT**

I'm createing a sqlite database using sql.js script.
The script loops over a table and stores the data to my database.
A user wants to see a progress bar of table looping. So, I want to create a callback function for each iteration of sql request.

Comment: You are still doing the same stuff as before in your `each` loop, so if that’s what is “blocking” here, then you have done nothing about it so far – a few `setTimeout` thrown in there don’t change anything about what the loop does. If `setTimeout` is used in such a situation (and it might not always be the best solution), then it is used to _replace_ the loop, by calling a function that processes smaller chunks of the data repeatedly (and kind-of recursively).

Comment: try this `setTimeout(function(){ $("#pbData").text(index + ' PROGRESS'); add_line_to_db(db,table_name,name,text); },1);`. but, i don't imagine this issue. What are text and name?

Comment: @SheraliTurdiyev some data for sql request. id and value.

Comment: @SheraliTurdiyev , you code gives an error:' Uncaught Database closed '

Comment: @trololo, why should you  create callback. Please, explain your question understandable

Comment: @SheraliTurdiyev updated

Comment: @trololo, i answered to your question. please, check it. if doesn't work, let me know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript is single threaded, any code you run on that thread will automatically block your UI.

If you have a lot of work to do asyncronously try using a WebWorker to run code in parallel.

Check out the MDN page about the javascript event loop:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Or this: http://blog.carbonfive.com/2013/10/27/the-javascript-event-loop-explained/

There's also a very good tool that visually simulates what the event loop does [here](http://latentflip.com/loupe/?code=JC5vbignYnV0dG9uJywgJ2NsaWNrJywgZnVuY3Rpb24gb25DbGljaygpIHsKICAgIHNldFRpbWVvdXQoZnVuY3Rpb24gdGltZXIoKSB7CiAgICAgICAgY29uc29sZS5sb2coJ1lvdSBjbGlja2VkIHRoZSBidXR0b24hJyk7ICAgIAogICAgfSwgMjAwMCk7Cn0pOwoKY29uc29sZS5sb2coIkhpISIpOwoKc2V0VGltZW91dChmdW5jdGlvbiB0aW1lb3V0KCkgewogICAgY29uc29sZS5sb2coIkNsaWNrIHRoZSBidXR0b24hIik7Cn0sIDUwMDApOwoKY29uc29sZS5sb2coIldlbGNvbWUgdG8gbG91cGUuIik7!!!PGJ1dHRvbj5DbGljayBtZSE8L2J1dHRvbj4%3D)

Comment: It is pity but you are right. only a web worker can help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead of `each()` iteration. it will work, i think. But it's not optimum way. because, inserting time is differently

```
var i = 0, howManyTimes = array.length, timeForInserting = 3000;
function iterate() {
    //other codes
    $("#pbData").text(i + ' PROGRESS');
    add_line_to_db(db,table_name,name,text);

    //other codes

    i++;
    if( i < howManyTimes ){
        setTimeout( iterate(), timeForInserting );
    }
}
iterate();
```

[How do I add a delay in a JavaScript loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop)

Comment: No. Unfortunally, It doesn't work. sql.js totaly freezes the UI. anyway thanks.