# Chart.js update() method only works once in the end instead of updating every iteration

Tags: javascript, chart.js, insertion-sort

```js
function insertSort(inputArray = myChart.data.datasets[0].data) {
    let inputArrayLength = inputArray.length;
    let outerIndex = 1;
    let innerIndex = 0;
    while(outerIndex<inputArrayLength) {
        innerIndex = outerIndex - 1;
        temp = outerIndex;
        while(innerIndex>=0){
            if (inputArray[temp]<inputArray[innerIndex]){
                inputArray[innerIndex] = [inputArray[temp], inputArray[temp] = inputArray[innerIndex]][0];
                temp = innerIndex;
                innerIndex--;
            } else {
                innerIndex--;
            }
        }
        sleep(1000);
        console.log('Intermediate result is: ', inputArray);
        myChart.data.datasets[0].data = inputArray;
        myChart.update();
        outerIndex++;
    }
    console.log('Final result is: ', inputArray);
    return true;
}
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  console.log('going in sleep');
  const date = Date.now();
  let currentDate = null;
  do {
    currentDate = Date.now();
  } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
  console.log('out of sleep');
}
let ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
let randomArray = Array.from({length: 10}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10+1));
let myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange', 'Blue', 'Blue', 'Blue', 'Blue'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: randomArray,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <button type="button" onclick="insertSort()">StartSorting</button>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400">
    </canvas>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have built a simple insertion sort algorithm in JavaScript, which sorts an array of ten random integers from the smallest to the largest.

- The result is visualised by using Chart.js library, ten bars of different heights are sorted and updated from the shortest to the tallest.

What I want to achieve now is: visualise each step of this sorting process. I introduced a ***sleep()*** function which basically delays the code execution and right after this ***sleep()*** function, I call ***myChart.update()*** to update the bars. But the result is not what I expected, it turned out that all bars were only updated once by the end of this code execution instead of being updated whenever a sorting step is completed.

Can anyone help? My code can be executed by C&P as a HTML file and run it in Chrome browser. Click **startSorting** button to have it sorted, and some simple debugging messages are available in the developer console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code blocks the UI, hence the console log messages and the updated chart can only be shown once its execution has completed (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/32316972/2358409).

Instead of using your own `sleep` function, you better use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) in order to schedule individual work portions. Below runnable code illustrates how this could work while the function `insertSort` was simplified and no longer does what it originally did.

```js
function insertSort(inputArray = myChart.data.datasets[0].data) {
    let inputArrayLength = inputArray.length;
    let outerIndex = 1;
    while(outerIndex<inputArrayLength) {
        setTimeout(() => {           
           myChart.data.datasets[0].data = Array.from({length: 10}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10+1));
           console.log('Intermediate result is: ', myChart.data.datasets[0].data.join(', '));
           myChart.update();
        }, 1000 * outerIndex);
        outerIndex++;
    }
    console.log('Final result is: ', inputArray.join(', '));
    return true;
}

let ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
let randomArray = Array.from({length: 10}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10+1));
let myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange', 'Blue', 'Blue', 'Blue', 'Blue'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: randomArray,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<button type="button" onclick="insertSort()">StartSorting</button>
<canvas id="myChart" height="100">
```